# Add HTML website from Visual Studio to Git

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have created a project in Visual Studio Online, and then cloned this repo in Visual Studio, I then tried to create a new project in this repo by choosing "new" from the "solutions" section in the home screen in team explorer window in Visual Studio, but I don't want to create a project that contains DLL, all I want to do is to create a basic html site with Angular functionality without DLL and stored in VSO, how can I do that?

Comment: Question not clear. Do you ask a way to create an empty project (where nor git, neither VSO doesn't change the problem) or do you ask for ignoring dlls (in that case look at the .gitignore file)

Comment: Hi Philippe, in Visual Studio you can either create a "project" or create a new "website". But when you are in Team Explorer, you have only the option to create a new project (which will include Dlls with it which I don't want). I want just a simple website that has Git as source control in Visual Studio Online. If you just follow what I wrote above in Visual Studio you would understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, by default dll files (also other build output files) will not be added to Source Control. So, no dlls will be checked in if you choose "New" from the "Solution" section in the Team Explorer.

Secondly, the "New" from the "Solution" actually opens the  New Project dialog in VS, if you create project this way and build the project, you will get the dll file as the output. But, no worries, just as I mentioned above, the dll files will not be checked in.

Comment: Hi @Vicky, thanks for your answer. So it's the same case when creating new project with dlls and creating new project without dlls?

Comment: @DavidHemsey, yes, by default dlls will not be added and checked in TFS version control.